# aurelia plugin.load is not a function error

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to run aurelia cli for the first time.  I got everything working save for the router view.  I keep getting the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: plugin.load is not a function
at Module...
```

here are my files:

**main.js**

```
import environment from './environment';

//Configure Bluebird Promises.
Promise.config({
  warnings: {
    wForgottenReturn: false
  }
});

export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .feature('resources');

  if (environment.debug) {
    aurelia.use.developmentLogging();
  }

  if (environment.testing) {
    aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-testing');
  }

  aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot());
}
```

**app.html**

```
<template>
  <require from="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```
export class App {
  configureRouter(config, router){
    this.router = router;
    config.title = 'Aurelia';
    config.map([
      { route: '', name: 'default', moduleId: 'default', nav: false, title: 'Default' }
    ]);
  }
}
```

**default.html**

```
<template>
    ${test}
</template>
```

**default.js**

```
export class DefaultApp {
    constructor(){
        this.test = 'TEST!';
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Aurelia</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body aurelia-app="main">
    <script src="scripts/vendor-bundle.js" data-main="aurelia-bootstrapper"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas as to why I keep getting this error?

Comment: Please post your index.html.

Comment: updated to include the index.html

Comment: Issue resolved see below

Answer (score 1):

The issue I had was that I had the default.html file inside a folder instead of next to the default.js.  Once moved, it all worked.